Why is Kubernetes generating 100s of CSRs?
27.x
When I tried to look at the logs of a pod, I got: Failed to load logs: Get "https://...?tailLines=502&timestamps=true": remote error: tls: internal error Reason: undefined (500)
When I look at the certificates using kubeadm they seem valid until next year and I had refreshed them in January.
When I look at kubectl get csr -A I have hundreads of pending csrs.

This issue is due to pending Certificate Signing Requests for nodes made by Kubelet running in each node. To check the csr pending nodes
kubectl get csr  --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp

Approve the csr for each node kubectl certificate approve <csr-id\>, if you have too many pending nodes
kubectl get csr  --no-headers | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kubectl certificate approve

Need more information about your node use kubectl describe nodes
As per the Official Kubernetes document on Enabling signed kubelet serving certificates: “One limitation is that the CSRs (Certificate Signing Requests) for these certificates cannot be automatically approved by the default signer in the kube-controller-manager - kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving. This will require action from the user or a third party controller.”
Hundreds of pending CSRs indicates a significant congestion in the certificate issuance process. Follow the below troubleshooting steps to limit the generating of CSRs and Log loading issues :

The CA server might be lacking the necessary resources to handle the load, so check Resource Availability like your CA server has sufficient CPU, memory, and storage resources.

Check configuration settings like request queue limits, and concurrency limits.

Verify that the certificates for your Kubernetes cluster match the domain you are trying to access.

Ensure the server is configured to allow TLS connections and has the appropriate certificates and CA bundle in place.

Make sure your Kubernetes version is compatible with the CA you are using.


Edit1:
Reverting tlsBootStrap to false: This might work temporarily, but it disables the automatic certificate management, requiring you to manually handle certificate renewals. It's a less ideal long-term solution
By approving the pending CSRs this may address the issue immediately, but you need to find the root cause of the excessive CSR generation based on the above steps provided in the answer section.
Also use the latest stable Kubernetes version to benefit from bug fixes and security enhancements.
As I am not able to comment because of less reputations I updated my response in this answer section as Edit1.

Are you saying this happens naturally? The cluster was ok 2 days ago and we don't do anything special apart run 3 master and 3 agenrts.

Ran your first command (thanks for the order by). It actually started happening 24 hours ago and funny enough on 2 separate clusters on 2 complete isolated physical networks. Both clusters are small 3, masters 3 agents. Do I check something specific with kubectl describe nodes? It looks good. All nodes are status READY. I haven't approved the CSRs yet.

I understand I turned on tlsBootStrap = true. Can I simply revert it back to false, by changing the config map and bouncning the services as per usual. This was enabled since day 1 installation (a few months) for the metrics if I recall, this only happened last 24 hours). Or If I approve all these CSR this can still come up on it own? Or we have to checkfor CSR every once a while?

Thanks. Do I need to look for anything special in the kubectl describe command? Everything looks "healthy". What should I look for? As far as as CA server we aren't using one. We installed using the internal kubernetes method if that makes sense or default kubernetes self signed cert, I guess. Is the reoccurring do I need to run a Cron and monitor CSRs. Why almost after months of running all of a sudden CSRs started popping up in last 24 hours, when there was none before apart the initial install?

I will mark your answer as approved when I confirm if approving all the CSRs worked.

I can confirm that approving all the CSRs has worked. What I'm trying to understand is the process... Do I need to run kubectl get csr on a cron and notify myself to go check the CSRs and approve before the list explodes becomes big?
